# Is there a weak homotopy equivalence between Sp(2n,ℂ)/U(n) and SU(n)?

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

This question, Is there a weak homotopy equivalence between Sp(2n,ℂ)/U(n) and SU(n)?, is at the end of a long string of my comments in

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296373/is-sp2n-mathbbc-un-isomorphic-to-sun

Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: The space $Sp(2n,{\mathbb C})/U(n)$ has the same homotopy type as $X=Sp_c(2n)/U(n)$ where $Sp_c(2n)$ is a maximal compact subgroup of $ Sp(2n,{\mathbb C})$ containing $U(n)$. But $X$ is the compact dual of $Sp(2n,{\mathbb R})/U(n)$ and is therefore a compact hermitian symmetrix space; consequently, it has non-trivial $H^2$ with $\mathbb C$ coefficients, whereas $SU(n)$ has trivial $H^2$. I am a little puzzled that  some people have  down-voted this question, since it seems interesting and non-trivial.

Comment: Ian Agol already answered the question in the link.

Comment: The first has cohomological dimension $\dim(Sp(2n)/U(n))=n^2+n$ and the second, $n^2-1$.

Comment: Cross-post of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297269/

Comment: I accept that the answer is easy (esp that of @YCor); but to downvote a new contributor who has very few points seems harsh. One could explain the set of of this site to newcomers.

Comment: set-up not set of